# Is there a way to automatically set a chart's Y-axis bounds based on the max/min values of the X-axis, but only the range displayed?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

So I have a chart that plots a value each day. The chart references the whole data range, but the X-axis is set via a macro to display usually only the last 3 months worth of data.

This creates a problem for the auto feature when setting the Y-axis bounds as whilst the maximum value in the past 3 months (what is shown on the chart) may be 10% say, there may be a value from a date before what is shown in the chart which may be much higher, say 90%. Despite not being shown in the chart, because it's still included in the underlying series, the chart automatically sets the Y-axis bounds to higher than 90% which squashes the data actually shown in the chart, leaving a lot of unnecessary white space.

Is there a way to set it so that it automatically adjusts the bounds based only on the range included in the X-axis, not the entire underlying series?

This is a simple example, but I have multiple charts that are updated daily with the ability to change the date range shown in the chart so it would be good to have it automated.

Comment: Instead of adjusting the axis, why not have the macro adjust the data range for the chart?

Comment: Create a "mirror" of your data range using IF statements to repeat each value or use NA() to return #N/A "error" depending on whether the data point is in your date scope or not. Chart this range instead. Then all the data points that lie outside your desired date range will have #N/A which means they will not be plotted (unlike zeroes or blanks which would be). Then Auto axis scaling should just work because it only considers plotted points. You can of course hide this "mirror" data range, put it on another sheet or whatever you want to do so it is not in the way.